# How does the sub-convex bound $ L(\tfrac{1}{2}, \pi \times \chi ) \ll_{F, \epsilon, \pi} C(\chi)^{\frac{1}{2}} $ relate to "elementary" number theory?

Tags: nt.number-theory

How do sub-convex bounds turn back into number theory?  As of around 2010, we get estimates of L-functions like this:
$$ L(\tfrac{1}{2}, \pi \times \chi ) \ll_{F, \epsilon, \pi} C(\chi)^{\frac{1}{2}} $$
$\pi$ is a  "cuspidal automorphic representation", and $\chi$ is a character.  The twisted L-function would look like this:
$$ L(s, \pi \times \chi) = \sum_{\mathfrak{m}} \lambda_{\pi \otimes \chi}(\mathfrak{m}) (N\mathfrak{m})^{-s}  $$
where $\mathfrak{m}$ indexes the , and $\chi$ is a character of conductor $\mathfrak{q}$.  The Hecke eigenvalues if they were to compute them look like this, are multiplicative:
$$ \lambda_{\pi \otimes \chi}(\mathfrak{m}) = \lambda_\pi(\mathfrak{m})\lambda_\chi(\mathfrak{m}) $$

My question is basic and somewhat procedural... How does the automorphic function and the respresentation and the number theory problem match up?  It looks like the number theory and the representation theory have been de-coupled.

Example $\pi$ could be a "[holomorphic Hilbert cusp form](https://www.lmfdb.org/ModularForm/GL2/TotallyReal/2.2.5.1/holomorphic/2.2.5.1-31.1-a)".  How do we interpret the sub-convexity bounds in terms of more familiar objects?  This seems to be related to the [Burgess](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327455/explicit-version-of-the-burgess-theorem?rq=1) theorem.

When I search for the Burgess formula all I get are complicated sums of Dirichlet characters:
$$ \sum_{N \leq n \leq N+H} \chi(n) \ll H^{1-\frac{1}{r}} q^{\frac{1}{4}+\epsilon}$$
There are no L-functions here or automorphic forms, yet.  Burgess' [1962](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/plms/s3-12.1.193) result says:
$$ L(\frac{1}{2}, \chi) \ll k^{\frac{7}{32}+\epsilon}  $$
where $\chi$ is a [Dirichlet character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_L-function) modulo $k$.  The constant $\frac{7}{32}$ seems interseting but there is also $L(\frac{1}{2}, \chi)\ll k^{\frac{1}{2}}$ in [1931](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1112/plms/s3-12.1.193).

Comment: I have no idea what the question is here. This post is all over the shop. First of all, subconvexity would be a bound $L(1/2, \pi \otimes \chi) \ll_{F,\pi} C(\chi)^{1/2 - \delta}$ for some fixed $\delta > 0$; $\delta = 0$ is the convexity bound. Next, $\lambda_{\pi \otimes \chi}(\mathfrak{m}) = \lambda_{\pi}(\mathfrak{m}) \chi(\mathfrak{m})$, at least if the conductors of $\pi$ and $\chi$ are coprime. You ask about more familiar objects - automorphic forms *are* the familiar objects. With regards to the Burgess theorem, this is subconvexity for $L(s,\chi)$, not $L(s,\pi \otimes \chi)$.

Comment: In any case, $L(s,\chi)$ is a $\mathrm{GL}_1$ $L$-function, not a $\mathrm{GL}_2$ one, so the convexity bound is $O(C(\chi)^{1/4})$, not $O(C(\chi)^{1/2})$; the optimal bound via Burgess' method is $O(C(\chi)^{3/16})$. Of course, you can think of this as a bound for the $\mathrm{GL}_2$ $L$-function $L(s,\chi)^2 = L(s,\pi \otimes \chi)$, where $\pi$ is an Eisenstein series.

Comment: @PeterHumphries I'm just trying to read the symbols here.  $L(s, \chi) = \sum \frac{\chi(n)}{n^s} = \prod \left(1 - \frac{\chi(p)}{p} \right)^{-1}$ as I could find on Wikipedia.  So $\pi$ is both the representation of $GL_2$ and it's also the Eisenstein series (or Maass form) or etc ?

Comment: An Eisenstein series is an automorphic form in the vector space of a noncuspidal automorphic representation. Similarly, a Hecke-Maass cusp form or a holomorphic Hecke eigenform is an automorphic form in the vector space of a cuspidal automorphic representation.

Comment: I should add to Peter's excellent answers that automorphic forms is a heavy subject. I recommend that you read a textbook (e.g. Bump or Goldfeld-Hundley) before asking questions. In particular, the definition of automorphic $L$-functions is itself a tricky thing and requires background reading. For Dirichlet characters modulo $q$, Burgess's bound is $L(s,\chi)\ll_{s,\varepsilon} q^{3/16+\varepsilon}$, and this was recently improved by Petrow-Young to $L(s,\chi)\ll_{s,\varepsilon} q^{1/6+\varepsilon}$. If it is not clear how this relates to bounds on character sums, I recommend that you read...

Comment: ... a textbook on analytic number theory as well (e.g. Montgomery-Vaughan).

Comment: I actually think this is a decent question and deserves a real answer. The comments here are a well-meant attempt to educate the poster out of some misconceptions, but aren't actually answering the main question. As someone working on the algebraic side of automorphic forms, I've often wondered the same thing: why do analytic number theorists care so much about subconvexity (or other) bounds for automorphic L-functions? What are these bounds useful for?

Comment: @DavidLoeffler I'm agreeing with you that textbooks are should most have answers.  On page 4 of Bump it says $L(s, \chi) = \prod_p (1 - \frac{\chi(p)}{p})^{-1}$ and yet the chapter is called "modular forms".  These objects like $\mathbb{A}^\times/F^\times$ are a little bit compact, so it's difficult to tell how much information is there... How complicated these objects are.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler:  Here are two applications of subconvexity.  The most spectacular one is to representations of integers by positive definite ternary quadratic forms --- a subject going back to the Gauss-Legendre three squares theorem.   A famous result of Duke & Schulze-Pillot (building on a breakthrough of Iwaniec) shows that if local conditions are met, then every sufficiently large square-free (to avoid some technical issues) integer is represented by a given ternary quadratic form.  A key input here is subconvexity for quadratic twists of modular form $L$-functions.

Comment: In a related vein, one can get the equidistribution of the lattice points $(x,y,z)$ with $x^2+y^2+z^2 =n$ (again say $n$ squarefree and not $7 mod 8$), with these lattice points projected down to the unit sphere.  One can also generalize this and study the three squares theorem in a totally real number field (which I think is part of a Hilbert problem, and was resolved by Cogdell, Piatetskii-Shapiro and Sarnak).

Comment: The second application of subconvexity which is especially striking is to the Quantum Unique Ergodicity conjectures of Rudnick and Sarnak.  This involves subconvexity for symmetric square $L$-functions, and certain triple product $L$-functions.  While subconvexity in these examples has not yet been achieved, one can make partial progress which together with other techniques has been enough for QUE in the holomorphic case (and very different ergodic methods work for Maass forms due to Lindenstrauss).

Comment: An application of QUE:  In a fundamental domain, the zeros of a Hecke eigenform of large weight get equidistributed with respect to the hyperbolic measure.

Comment: Bump's book explains Dirichlet character $L$-functions first because they are simpler, and easier to understand, than modular form $L$-functions, but involve many of the same ideas. The goal is to learn Dirichlet $L$-functions first and use them as a guide in studying modular form $L$-functions, and then on to higher automorphic forms, not to try to learn everything at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straightforward application of subconvexity is to bounds to sums of the form

$$ \sum_{ n < X} \chi(n) a_n(f) $$ where $f(q) = \sum_n a_n(f) q^n$ is a modular form, or to the analogous sequences of Fourier coefficients arising from other modular forms. It's slightly easier to work with sums of the form $$ \sum_{n < X} \Psi(\frac{n}{X} ) \chi(n) a_n (f)$$ where $\Psi$ is a smooth function supported on $[0,1]$.

These functions have bounds of the form $ O ( \min (X, k))$ (where $k$ is the conductor of the character and a classical modular form $f$ is fixed), and subconvexity allows you to improve this in the range $X \approx k$.

This is perfectly elementary, although, if you think the sum $\sum_{n=N}^{N+H} \chi(n)$ is complicated, maybe you will not like this.

One perspective on this sum, primarily seen in the work of Fouvry, Kowalski, and Michel, is that one should replace $\chi(n)$ here by a more general function that is periodic mod $k$, for example $\chi$ composed with a polynomial and expect, and hope to prove, similar results.

---

A second application of subconvexity is by period integral formulas which relate special values of $L$-functions to integrals of modular forms or other automorphic forms. Subconvexity gives good bounds for these integrals, which often show up in practical problems. Lucia has explained examples of this beautifully in the comments, so I won't attempt to.

---

Finally, a broad hope is that any subconvexity result represents progress on the Riemann hypothesis, and proving subconvexity in all these different cases might lead us to a clue which helps to prove the Riemann hypothesis. (More generally, cases of the Riemann hypothesis are used in a wide variety of arguments, and subconvexity results can remove some of them, rendering the results unconditional.)

Comment: To add to Will's last point, subconvex bounds $L(1/2,\pi) \ll C(\pi)^{1/4 - \delta}$ for some $\delta > 0$ are progress towards the generalised Lindelof hypothesis, which states that one can take any $\delta < 1/4$, and the generalised Lindelof hypothesis is implied by the generalised Riemann hypothesis.